# Alternative to TransactionScope of System.Transaction assembly in .net core framework

Tags: transactions, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

The System.Transaction assembly is not part of the .net core framework at the moment (see https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2949). In my application (asp.net core mvc) I need to use TransactionScope for transaction handling.

#### Question:

Is there an alternative transaction handling which works with the .net core framework? I have tried to use Castle.Transactions as an alternative, which is also not supported at the moment.

Comment: As the [thread you referenced](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2949) says, there is no plan to implement System.Transactions soon. You can see how TransactionScope is [implemented in full .NET](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Transactions/System/Transactions/TransactionScope.cs), but recreating the exact behavior of TransactionScope in .NET Core is beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: My hope was to find a nuget package like Castle.Transactions which could serve as an alternative to System.TransactionScope. How do they handle transactions in .NET Core?

Comment: There is some recent activity on GIthub https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/dev/api/src/System.Transactions but couldnt find a nuget package. Full support for Distributed/Ambient transactions might not be too far away,

Comment: I would encourage you to upvote and/or comment on the official issue for this missing feature: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/13532

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Update 2**
.NET Core 2.0 is out now. You can use this API. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-2.0

**Update**
System.Transactions will be available in 
NET Core 2.0. See https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md for details on upcoming releases.

**Original answer**

System.Transactions (or ambient transactions) is not implemented in .NET Core 1.0.0 but may be implemented in future versions.

You can work around this by using explicit transactions.

```
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            {
               // transaction.Commit();
               // transaction.Rollback();
            }
        }
```

Comment: This is out of date, right? https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/dev/api/src/System.Transactions/src

Comment: It isn't released yet. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/10089 but yes, this plus many other APIs are being added to make .NET Core more compatible with .NET Framework.

Comment: Does .net core 2.0 supports Ambient and distributed transaction?

Comment: I get Enlisting in Ambient transactions is not supported with .net core 2 using the example here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope?view=netcore-2.0

Comment: @natemcmaster Thanks for keeping us up to date!

Answer (score 4):

Just wanted to leave a comment here in case anybody wandered by this post while researching this issue. I ran into this randomly on .net core 2.1 using Dapper, which includes System.Data.SqlClient 4.5.0 by default. Adding version System.Data.SqlClient 4.5.1 independently via nuget worked. So it seems this has been fixed as of 4.5.1.

The following are the relevant sections of my csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Dapper" Version="1.50.5" />
   <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.5.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```